# Stuck in while loop in GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a GUI that first accepts an input number from user and makes the corresponding button green. Now I run another python script that scans an apriltag(sort of QR Code) and returns an ID and writes it into a file placed in same folder. The code I've attached includes print statement at various point("Done", "phew","haha"). On running the GUI the command Done is printed first, followed by phew and haha(multiple times). However the button does not change its colour to green, it only changes its colour when the apriltag is detected by the camera. The code is attached. The function is called when I press the OK button in my GUI.

I have tried to include delays and also tried to use threading. But none of these methods worked.

```
import Tkinter
def action3():

    f = open("test.txt","r")          
    data = f.read()
    y = int(str(data))
    f.close()
    f = open("test.txt","w")
    f.write("0")
    f.close()
    x = int(e.get())
    f = open("test.txt","r")
    data = f.read()
    y = int(str(data))
    f.close()
    print("Done")

    if (x == 1):
          b1['bg'] = 'green'
          b2['bg'] = 'white'
          b3['bg'] = 'white'
          b4['bg'] = 'white'
          print("phew")
          #time.sleep(2)

    elif (x == 2):
          b1['bg'] = 'white'
          b2['bg'] = 'green'
          b3['bg'] = 'white'
          b4['bg'] = 'white'
          print("phew")

    elif (x == 3):
          b1['bg'] = 'white'
          b2['bg'] = 'white'
          b3['bg'] = 'green'
          b4['bg'] = 'white'
          print("phew")

    elif (x == 4):
          b1['bg'] = 'white'
          b2['bg'] = 'white'
          b3['bg'] = 'white'
          b4['bg'] = 'green'        
          print("phew")

#time.sleep(5)




   while(y==0):             ##Update y
          f = open("test.txt","r")
          data = f.read()
          y=int(str(data))
          print("Haha")
          f.close()
          time.sleep(2)

##Code for GUI
b1 = Button(window, text="Box1", bg='white', width=30, height=13)
b1.grid(row=1, sticky=W)

b2 = Button(window, text="Box2", bg = 'white', width = 30,height = 13)
b2.grid(row=2, sticky=W)

b3 = Button(window, text="Box3", bg = 'white', width = 30,height = 13)
b3.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

b4 = Button(window, text="Box4", bg = 'white', width = 30,height = 13)
b4.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

bget = Button(window, text="OK", bg='pink', width = 10,height = 
2,command=action3)

bget.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=E)

e = Entry(window)
e.grid(row=3, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: you will always get `y = 0`, you need to update the value for `y` to break the loop

Comment: The y will be updated from another script. That script detects a tag and depending on its ID it updates the file test.txt

Comment: There is no GUI. Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: I have updated the code and added the GUI part